# how do i stop this "IndexOutOfBoundsException" issue?

Tags: java, libgdx

So I the app lets a user place down blocks on a grid, if the user lines up 3 or more blocks with the same suit, or color, then something happens. When player places a block I call this method:

```
   blocks_.add(new Block(new Vector2(rect_mouse.x, rect_mouse.y), blocks_.get(0).blockID, blockCount));
```

When you place 3 or more together I call these methods:

```
    blocks_.removeValue(blocks_.get(left_bravo_indexNum), true);
    blocks_.removeValue(blocks_.get(center_charlie_indexNum), true);
    blocks_.removeValue(blocks_.get(right_alpha_indexNum), true);


    stack:
    Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 13
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array.get(Array.java:125)
at com.jrp.mygearapp.GameScreen.touchUp(GameScreen.java:1443)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.processEvents(LwjglInput.java:297)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:186)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
```

This was intended to remove the blocks, but it resulted in this IndexOutOfBoundsException. Is there a way to prevent this error?

This could be occurring because the array auto sorts the number of elements and lowers the number to the correct number of elements in the array, and I still have elements that are labeled higher then the size of the array. I am still a novice, so my analysis could be incorrect. Please alert me if this is the case and help me find a fix. 
Thanks.

***edirted**** TouchUp() function-------

```
   @Override
     public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {

    if (button == 0)  {

        display_blockCheck = false;

        ////set blockCount to the size of blockArray so blocks can properly be indexed              
        blockCount = blocks_.size;

        if (!overlap) {

            Gdx.app.log("Block Added", "x: " + x + " y: " + y);

            updateQueueBlocks();


            //add block
            Vector2 rect_vector = new Vector2(rect_mouse.x, rect_mouse.y);
            Block block = new Block(rect_vector,blocks_.get(0).blockID, blocks_.size);

            blocks_.add(block);             

     if (center_charlie_suit == "Square") {

                center_charlie_bool = true;

                if (right_bravo_suit == "Square") {

                    right_bravo_bool = true;

                    if (right_alpha_suit == "Square") {

                        Gdx.app.log("3-pair", "Square:345:lr");

                        right_alpha_bool = true;

                        //call 3-pair event
                        blocks_.removeValue(blocks_.get(center_charlie_indexNum), true);
                        blocks_.removeValue(blocks_.get(right_alpha_indexNum), true);
                        blocks_.removeValue(blocks_.get(right_bravo_indexNum), true);
                        }
                }
            }
```

the rest is just really long and just checks for other blocks next to each other..

Comment: First try to add the stacktrace, second most likely the error will be in that long line, how about split things a little but so you can get a better stacktrace? Create an instance and pass it as argument. This error means that you are calling an invalid index for an array/list/etc.  I bet is here: `new Vector2(rect_mouse.x, rect_mouse.y)` but I don't know what is Vector2.

Comment: You can add the stack trace to the question.

Comment: sry for the ignorance, what do you mean by splitting things up?  Vector2 is the cords of the block, the new Block is an instance of the class Block, blockID is what type of block, and block count is the index number of the block that is within the array

Comment: Instead of adding `blocks_.add( new BLock(new Vector....(` First create `Vector2 vector... Block block = new Block(vector).. blocks_.add(block)...` That way you will ensure that one by one, all your instances can be created.

Comment: Well, if your blocks_ is instance of com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array then seems that Ray's answer is right. You might be having get issues because you use indexes as you are removing elements.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that `blocks_.get(0)` has an element when you call that line? What is the content of `com.jrp.mygearapp.GameScreen.touchUp(GameScreen.java:1443)`

Comment: ok so I separated them like this:           'Vector2 rect_vector = new Vector2(rect_mouse.x, rect_mouse.y);
    Block block = new Block(rect_vector,blocks_.get(0).blockID, blockCount);
    
    blocks_.add(block);'

Comment: sry porfiriopartida, I didn't see the link that shows more comments, my touchup() is pretty big, although im changing it in the future for obvious reasons(I think the process of checking for 3-in-a-row or more could be used with less code), ill pos it up..

Answer (score 1):

You're right, as you remove the blocks, the indexes change.

You don't show what type of Collection `blocks_` is (Vector2?, did you write it?), however, rather than tracking the indices of the elements, simply track the elements themselves and call `remove()` to find and remove that element.

Comment: public Array<Block> blocks_ = new Array<Block>(); and it is within the same class with the above code..

Comment: You are calling blocks_.get(0), can you update the code to add where is blocks_.add.. called? or does this class have any element by default?

Comment: are you saying "can I update the code to return the indexPosition of the blocks being removed?"  the Block class has a few elements public Block(Vector2 pos, int id, int index, int color, int suit) {

Comment: Where do the indices`left_bravo_indexNum`, etc, come from? If you instead do something like `Block left_bravo_block = blocks_.get(wherever you're getting left_bravo_indexNum from);` you can call `removeValue(left_bravo_block)` all day with no problem.

Comment: ok, left_alpha is a rect 2 spaces left of the center rect, left bravo is 1 space left of the center I have 2 rects in each direction of the center rect, on TouchUp() event, I check the intersections of each alpha and bravo rect against any Block that it might be intersecting with, so if left_alpha_rect is over block_.get(12) I make it so left_alpha_indexNum = block_.get(12).indexNum, and I figure that will give me the index number/the correct block to remove...

Comment: And so it does, but the index is only correct until you remove the first one from the Array, then any blocks after that one have new indices. So, instead of storing the index, which won't be valid later, store the object, then remove it from the Array.

Comment: Okay, I see what your saying, the index aint gonna work in this case, how do I store the object?  lol im sorry....

Comment: See my first comment on this answer.

Comment: I appreciate the info, at least im that much closer to solving this, but do you think you can provide a tutorial or article contrasting "removing the indices" and "removing the elements", I just don't see how you can a.)store the element  b.)remove an element without knowing its index/address.  much thx again...